# Minecraft Launcher has Grayed-out Profile Settings

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

Why do I have grayed out options for the Profile Editor?
[image]

Comment: Is this the old launcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't noticed that the check-boxes to make those editable are there, but they blend in with the background.

Comment: Is your question answered or are you trying to find out what those boxes do?

Comment: @Reflexive It's already answered; I forgot to accept it though.